# How to use one table (ods) file as a base for another table file?

Tags: gui, clipboard, libreoffice, standard, table

I have an accounting ledger table (`.ods`) file which should be the base for other table files.

This table file should be the base for other table files such as:

- 2023.ods
- 2024.ods
- 2025.ods

These are year files each of which contains a ledger for a given year.

---

Of course, each year I could just copy-paste the template ledger file and rename the copied file, to, say, 2023.ods but I wonder if it bears any benefits to "export" or "include" the template file into such new files (such as 2023.ods).

So, my problem is to determine between mere copy-pasting each new year to exporting/including each new year.

I don't seek a primarily opinion based answer but more of a standardization-based prons and cons answer also explaining what to do and how to do it.

Comment: This seems to have very little to do with Linux/UNIX. Though we do allow questions about software running *on* such an operating system, this isn't really the optimal place to ask about how to do something with spreadsheet software. Have you considered our sister site Superuser.com, where there's *thousands* of good answers about libreoffice and a lot more specific experience?

Comment: @MarcusMüller No I haven't considered that. For now I keep the question here but if some mod prefer to migrate I'll have no criticism.

Comment: As said, I don't think it's off-topic, just that Superuser.com might already contain an answer, or a lot more people with libreoffice-specific expertise than us few here ;) From my side, you're most welcome to keep that question here!

Comment: My opinion is that you really should use a dbase and learn some sql. There are places for spreadsheets, but this type of data is better in a database.

Comment: @oldfred I have learned a bit of SQL in the past (not to become an expert in it) and my opinion is that I and other people who are not SQL experts shouldn't use SQL to manage these data structures with software other than LibreOffice Calc, because It's just a small simple freelancer's personal, single-sided, debit-based, ledger and mastering enough SQL just for that sake is in my opinion an redundant (an "overkill").

Comment: Someone may want to flag the question to migrate it to SuperUser.

Comment: Well I can't delete the question and can't flag for migration either; I do think SuperUser is better than AskUbuntu for this particular task but I might be wrong. I ask again (last time) for some user here to flag for migration and for a possible next case about LibreOffice Calc I might just ask on SuperUser directly.

Comment: @searcher [You cannot because you're an unregistered user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361237/355310).

Answer (score 0):

LibreOffice already supports this kind of [templating](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.2/km/text/shared/guide/manage_templates.html), as does OpenOffice and related programs. It's fairly common to want to start working on a **new** spreadsheet that has the same basic setup (sheets, "macros" - i.e. scripting, cell formulae, etc) as other similar spreadsheets without having to manually copy an existing file and clear out the old data.

If you create the template spreadsheet and save it as a [`.ots`](https://fileinfo.com/extension/ots) (OpenDocument Spreadsheet Template) file, then whenever you open it in LO Calc, it will be named "Untitled 1", "Untitled 2", etc until you save it with a "real" filename (with a `.ods` extension) using the `File -> Save As...` menu option.

If you ever need to update the template, you have to Use `Save As...` again to save it as a `.ots` template file again.  You can overwrite your original template file or save it with a new template filename (which is useful if you want to keep a historical archive of previous versions of the template...not as good as real revision management software like `git` but better than nothing).

---

PS: I use .ots files to maintain a LO Calc spreadsheet for an RPG character sheet editor - open up the template file and it's ready to create a brand new character without risk of accidentally overwriting the clean template.  A spreadsheet isn't the best tool for this job, but a) it's cross-platform (i.e. it runs on anything that LO itself runs on), and b) it saved me the hassle of writing a lot of very fiddly graphical user-interface code (each character requires multiple sheets of tabulated data for their stats, skills, equipment, etc) in python or whatever.